# trying to find a clear simple email package and example top to bottom, in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, gmail

I am trying to build / find a solution to make my nodejs send email to specific address I get via HTTP.POST().
My needs are simple - I just need to send a short email, for a specific address every time someone is calling my http.post().
I will be happy to also send one small file of HTML as attachment, but if it's complicated I will simply parse the html/text into the mail (it's a short text anyway).

Problem is I don't understand what is needed to create such a module.

1. I tried playing with 'mailcomposer' , but it seems only to be used to create a 
   format of mail without sending it.
2. I see that 'nodemailer' costs almost a $1,000 to use, so it's also out of the question.
3. Tried also to use 'mailover' with a gmail account (nothing fancy - like in their [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailover)), but code is running, and sends no email / no warnings / no error / nothing... 
   Not sure if it's a working module or not.

Any ideas where to find a simple clear, STEP-BY-STEP example of how to use a mailer in NODEJS? I have no knowladge with email protocols and that's why I also look for a step-by-step example.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much more clear and easy to use service named "[sendgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid)".
The node Js examples on how to log / integrate / run are much better then mailchimp / mandrill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mandrill

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.nodejs.html

This is how you put it out, now to do some mailing you could do:

```
mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
var message = {
    "html": "<p>Example HTML content</p>",
    "text": "Example text content",
    "subject": "example subject",
    "from_email": "message.from_email@example.com",
    "from_name": "Example Name",
    "to": [{
            "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "name": "Recipient Name",
            "type": "to"
        }],
    "headers": {
        "Reply-To": "message.reply@example.com"
    },
    "important": false,
    "track_opens": null,
    "track_clicks": null,
    "auto_text": null,
    "auto_html": null,
    "inline_css": null,
    "url_strip_qs": null,
    "preserve_recipients": null,
    "view_content_link": null,
    "bcc_address": "message.bcc_address@example.com",
    "tracking_domain": null,
    "signing_domain": null,
    "return_path_domain": null,
    "merge": true,
    "merge_language": "mailchimp",
    "global_merge_vars": [{
            "name": "merge1",
            "content": "merge1 content"
        }],
    "merge_vars": [{
            "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "vars": [{
                    "name": "merge2",
                    "content": "merge2 content"
                }]
        }],
    "tags": [
        "password-resets"
    ],
    "subaccount": "customer-123",
    "google_analytics_domains": [
        "example.com"
    ],
    "google_analytics_campaign": "message.from_email@example.com",
    "metadata": {
        "website": "www.example.com"
    },
    "recipient_metadata": [{
            "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "values": {
                "user_id": 123456
            }
        }],
    "attachments": [{
            "type": "text/plain",
            "name": "myfile.txt",
            "content": "ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
        }],
    "images": [{
            "type": "image/png",
            "name": "IMAGECID",
            "content": "ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
        }]
};
var async = false;
var ip_pool = "Main Pool";
var send_at = "example send_at";
mandrill_client.messages.send({"message": message, "async": async, "ip_pool": ip_pool, "send_at": send_at}, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    /*
    [{
            "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "status": "sent",
            "reject_reason": "hard-bounce",
            "_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123"
        }]
    */
}, function(e) {
    // Mandrill returns the error as an object with name and message keys
    console.log('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
    // A mandrill error occurred: Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
});
```

As pointed out here:

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks , I will look into it.

Comment: If it's working please consider putting this as the accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok- the whole mandrill - mailchimp setup is too confusing and annoying, they charge me $20 just for registration before I can even setup one email for testing.
Anyone have something else? I am ok with paying but I want to see the system is easy to setup and works before I pay...